# Export Subarray and email each section

Tags: php, multidimensional-array, export

I have a multidimensional array that is like this:

```
Array ( 
    [email1@fake.com] => Array (
        [0] => Array ( 
            [asin] => B004HFS6Z0 
            [title] => Kindle, Wi-Fi, Graphite, 6" Display
            [price] => 114.00 
            [map] => 125.00 ) ) 
    [email2@fake.com] => Array ( 
        [0] => Array ( 
            [asin] => B004CYX17O 
            [title] => Rizzy Home Apple 10-Piece Comforter Set, King 
            [price] => 502.80 
            [map] => 520.00 ) ) )
```

What I am trying to do is export the sub array under the email address into a file, then email it to the email address.  So far, I've only been able to export both subarrays into a single file and haven't been able to get it to overwrite the file for the second sub array.

Here is the code I am working with:

```
require('export-xls.class.php');
    $filename = 'email.xls';
    $xls = new ExportXLS($filename);
    $header[] = "ASIN";
    $header[] = "Title";
    $header[] = "Retail";
    $header[] = "MAP";
    $xls->addHeader($header);   

//create temp csv file and email from subarray
foreach($map_check2 as $email => $value) {
//$fp = fopen('uploads/email.csv', 'w+');

foreach($value as $subkey => $subvalue) {
    //echo $email . "<br>";
    //print_r($subvalue) . "<br>";
    //fputcsv($fp, $subvalue);

    $xls->addRow($subvalue);


}
    $xls->emailFile();

}
```

I need to export it to an excel file and have been using the export-xls.class to do so.  I would have used the csv but periodically there will be commas in values in the array.

emailFile() is:

```
    public function emailFile() {

    #build the xls
    $xls = $this->buildXLS();

    $fp = fopen("uploads/email.xls", "w+");
    fwrite($fp, $xls);
    fclose($fp);        
}
```

Does anyone have any thoughts?  Or does that make sense?

Comment: @Reg: what is the issue here? Are you not able to write to the XLS file? Or not able to send the email? Where is the code that is sending email - I think it is part of the export-xls class?

Comment: i havent got as far as the email yet.  im mostly concerned about creating the file but only having it show the last subarray when i open it but it is showing both subarrays together.

Comment: i am thinking it  should create the file from the first subarray then when it loops back thru it should overwrite the original file for the but it is appending for some reason i cant figure out.

Comment: @Reg: please see my response. You are correct that it should overwrite the file because you are using w+ mode. But I think the problem might be elsewhere that I've explained in my response. I've no understanding of the class that you are using but I think it might just make sense.

Comment: Thank you for your help.  Let me play with it and I'll see if I can get it to work.  I think you are absolutly correct about what it is doing.

Comment: @Reg: cool! great, let me know if it worked or if it didn't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems in your inner foreach loop, where you are doing `$xls->addRow($subvalue)`, it keeps on adding all email sub-arrays. I think you should call some function inside the outer foreach but before the inner one, to clean the rows that have already been added to $xls.

Here is a test run that I could think of:

1. first call to the outer foreach is made - $email = email1@fake.com
2. first call to the inner foearch is made - calls $xls->addrow() for each of the values of the "email1@fake.com" array
3. first call to $xls->emailFile() is called that opens "email.xls" in w+ mode and writes the contents to the file
4. second call to the outer foreach is made - $email = email2@fake.com
5. second call to the inner foearch is made - calls $xls->addrow() for each of the values of the "email2@fake.com" array. **Note -** *I think at this point the rows added earlier to $xls in step 2 still exist and this might be the issue. If yes, you need to some cleanup either before the inner foreach starts or in the $this->buildXLS() method*
6. second call to $xls->emailFile() is called that opens "email.xls" in w+ mode and writes the contents to the file that includes values for both the subarrays.

I'm not sure what is the purpose of $this->buildXLS() and have ignored it for my explanation above.

Does the above make sense?